# Reindex fail due to SearchContextMissingException

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

My company is using elasticsearch 2.3.4.
We have a cluster that contains 38 ES nodes, and we've been having a problem with reindexing some of our data lately...
We've reindexed before very large indexes and had no problems, but recently, when trying to reindex much smaller indexed (less than 10GB) - we get : "SearchContextMissingException [No search context found for id [XXX]]".
We have no idea what's causing this problem or how to fix it. We'd like some guidance. 
Has anyone saw this exception before?

Comment: Are you reindexing using spark  ( hive , or anything using elasticsearch-hadoop ) ? There were few issues with elasticsearch spark with same exception

Comment: i'm using elasticsearch's reindex API

Answer (score 2):

From github comments on issues related to [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18411#issuecomment-219759493) , i think this can be avoided by changing batch size  :

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html):

By default _reindex uses scroll batches of 1000. You can change the batch size with the size field in the source element:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source",
    "size": 100
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest",
    "routing": "=cat"
  }
}
```

Comment: but according to the documentation the size field isn't the batch size, it's the number of documents that will be reindexed into the index

Comment: this is size inside "source"  object .  btw I was quoting from documentation :-)

Comment: oh.. sorry, didn't saw it.I'll try it and let ou know :)

Comment: tough luck , sorry ! but this seems to be definitely part  of few PR's and discussions in their repo and should be patched in more recent version .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an index that holds many huge documents. I had to reduce the batch size down to 10. (100 and 50 both didn't work).

This was the request that worked in the end:

```
POST _reindex?slices=5&refresh
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index",
    "size": 10
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest_index"
  }
}
```

You should also set the slices to the number of shards you have in your index.